# Loading relationship model in Ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have certain doubts with respect to Ember Data.
I have a post and comments model.

```
//post.js
comments: DS.hasMany('comment')

//blog.js
post: DS.belongsTo('post')
```

I can create a **comment** for a particular "post" using

```
let blogPost = this.get('store').findRecord('post', 1);
let comment = this.get('store').createRecord('comment', {
   post: blogPost
});
```

But how can i fetch all the comments for a particular post?
Like, I have multiple posts which has  many comments and i want all the comments for a particular post id, say posts/id/comments

**What is the right way to fetch the comments for a particular post id from the store and server?**

The server response i get is only the id's of the comments while "findRecord"ing a post.
I am following the REST API format and using REST Adapter and REST serializer for customizations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a many ways to get these records loaded into the store. How you choose to do it depends on how the back end is set up. The easiest options are using the child records in a template, or doing a query. The instructions below only apply to apps using a REST adapter (since JSONAPI requests are standardized).

Let's start with using the records in a template.

In the route, fetch the post and return it in the model hook:

```
// post.js route    
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id)
  },
});
```

Pass the model and its child records to a component:

```
// post.hbs route template
{{some-component comments=model.comments}}
```

Then use the comments in that component:

```
{{#each comments as |comment|}}
   <p>{{comment.note}}<p>
{{/each}}
```

You should find that using the comments in a template triggers GET requests to the ids that came back with your initial post fetch, such as `/comments/1`, `/comments/2`, etc. In the component's actions, you can access the comments as `this.get('comments')`

Another option is to specify a query parameter to be received and processed by the back end.

```
// post.js route    
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('comments', {post: params.post_id})
  },
});
```

The code above will make a GET request to /comments?post=1. The back end is responsible for filtering through the database and returning only the records that belong to the post. Since model is a collection of comments, you'd use the results of the above in a template like this:

```
{{#each model as |comment|}}
  <p>{{comment.note}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Just want to tell you your answers are great with detailed explanation. Please keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks, i would like to request the comments like, post/postID/comments not like the above mentioned. Is it possible to request like that naturally without using any customizations in adapters?

Comment: No, you would need to make an adapter and override urlFor to do nested urls. Another option is to use an addon like https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates