# ember has many with async true

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I has many relation in my ember app but it is not working recursively.
here is my model.
-->tree.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
       parent  : DS.attr(), 
       parentId : DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: "0"}),
       childrens: DS.hasMany('menu', {async:true}),    
       name    : DS.attr(),
 });
```

route code-->

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
      model: function() {   
          return this.store.findAll('treeview');       
      }  
});
```

hbs-->>

```
{{#each model as |tree|}}
<div class="col-lg-12">
{{#unless tree.parentId}}
{{tree.name}}
  {{#if tree.childrens}}
    {{#each tree.childrens as |childmenu|}}
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-left:30px;">
      {{sub-tree-view tree = tree}}
    </div>  
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}  
{{/unless}} 
</div>
{{/each}}
```

sub-tree-view component js file -->

```
 showRecord:function(){     
    let self = this; 
    let tree = self.get('tree');
    var test = tree.get('childrens'); }.property(),
```

But it not calling the model again with children id .
With hasmany relation it should call the menu model recursively but it is not making the request again. How to deal with the has many relationship data.?

Comment: I don't think I understand? What's the goal? Also, what's the template look like of that component?

Comment: Children is having has many relationship so it should make the request again, but it is not calling any requesh

Comment: Try passing the child records to a component, like `{{my-component childrens=treeview.childrens}}` and I think it will make the request for the children.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255025/loading-relationship-model-in-ember-data

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to have a new request made at every node of a tree structure?